# Accessing Registry on windows 7 C#

Tags: c#, windows-7, registry

I am attempting to make an updater program, that when updates it writes a build number into the windows 7 registry which the main program reads when checking for updates. I've gone through the UAC virtualization kb at microsoft's page, and have found nothing. My app.manifest has

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
```

and yet, when i look in HKEY_Local_Machine\Software the build entry is not there, i dont even see it in HKEY_USERS\_Classes\VirtualStore\Machine\Software either.

the code i'm using to enter into registry is

```
            Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\build");
        RegistryKey myKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\build", true);

        myKey.SetValue("build", "3", RegistryValueKind.String);
```

any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: What is your build target platform? x86, x64 or anyCpu?

Comment: When you say it isn't in `HKEY_USER`, you mean it isn't in `HKCU\Software`, or isn't in the UAC virtualization area?

Comment: built for x86... @Ben Voigt - its not in either. i checked both at the runtime of the updater.

Comment: If you are running on a 64bit environment please check the following location. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\...

Comment: ok, found the registry entry, thanks! now one more question. if others use the updater on x86 or x64, will it go to the same place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is targetting x86 platforms, when running on an x64 system, it will use the corresponding registry node with the following names:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ or HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node.

So, if you set platform target to x86 for your build, on x86 systems it will go under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE whereas on x64 systems it will go under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node which is a reserved node for applications running on WOW64(Windows 32-bit on Windows 64-bit) mode.

For more information see [Registry Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384235%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)