# Accessing windows registry in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, registry, sql-server-2012-express

I am trying to get all the SQL Instances installed on a local machine with the help of following code:

```
RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server");
string[] instances = (string[])rk.GetValue("InstalledInstances");

if (instances.Length > 0)    //Error
{
    foreach (string instance in instances)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(instance);
    }
}
```

It is giving the following exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I've manually checked the 'Registry-Editor' and the specified keys exist, also there are two SQL Instances on my system.

Now please tell me why it is not accessing the required key value?

Comment: I predict that you're running 32-bit code on a 64-bit OS.

Comment: See this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799584/accessing-registry-on-windows-7-c-sharp?rq=1)

Comment: But "InstalledInstances" does not exist under "Microsoft SQL Server" key.

Comment: You might need to run your code with elevated privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code on my 64-bit machine.  It worked fine.  Make sure you platform is set to AnyCPU or x64 but not x86

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This line could be the issue string[] instances = (string[])rk.GetValue("InstalledInstances");

Because RegistryKey.GetValue Method (String) returns a object and you are casting that in  to string[]

before casting it to string[] you should check if the returned value is not null

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct because if GetValue returned null then the cast to string[] would cause an error, since you can't cast a null value into a string array. His error seems to occur after this though, which tells me its not returning null and its successfully casting to a string array.